# API Key Mailgun not defined in Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble running my node.js app. I have a node project running version 8. I am having trouble with using mailgun. I have my API keys but they are not working in my project. I am using mailgun 0.18. When I try to run the project I get this

```
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759901+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:16
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759957+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new Error('apiKey value must be defined!')
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759960+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759962+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759964+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: apiKey value must be defined!
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759966+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Mailgun (/app/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib./mailgun.js:16:13)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759968+00:00 app[web.1]: at create (/app/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:234:10)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759970+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/mail/emailActivation.js:4:38)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759972+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759974+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759976+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759978+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759980+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759982+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759984+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759986+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/apiRoutes.js:11:18)
2020-01-01T09:56:06.759987+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)

2020-01-01T09:56:06.772146+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-01-01T09:56:06.772673+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-01-01T09:56:06.775514+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! prop-manager@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-01-01T09:56:06.775710+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-01-01T09:56:06.775979+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-01-01T09:56:06.776266+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the prop-manager@1.0.0 start script.
2020-01-01T09:56:06.776535+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-01-01T09:56:06.785682+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-01-01T09:56:06.785816+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-01-01T09:56:06.785888+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs /2020-01-01T09_56_06_778Z-debug.log
2020-01-01T09:56:06.857607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-01T09:56:06.831227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1`
```

I tried to change the node version and play with it but I have my keys and website that are working. I dont know why it is not working with a good api key. The code is

````
const appSettings = require('../appSettings');
const api_key = appSettings.getSetting('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
const DOMAIN = appSettings.getSetting('support.example.com');
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN });
const sendMail = require('./sendMail');```
````

Can someone direct me what I should do to fix the project. I have working keys and such. thanks

```
getSetting: function (name) {
    var setting = this.settings.find(setting => (setting.name == name));
    if (setting) return setting.value;

    // defer to environment if we don't have a setting by the requested name.
    if (process.env[name] !== undefined) return process.env[name];

    // null indicates setting not found
    return null;
},
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log(api_key)` to make sure it has the value you expect before calling the `mailgun` function? Also, could you share the code for `appSettings.getSetting`

Comment: I just added the extra code. Maybe I should follow the example on mailgun instead. this was to setup defaults. What do you think? If I need to paste more code I will.

Comment: Did you check what the value of `api_key` is?